# Core Data export and mail in Xcode

Tags: xml, email, pdf, core-data, export

I created an App that uses core data and I want to export the core data into a form that can be mailed and/or synced on a later version of this app. Can you please let me know 
1- which form (XML, CSV, PDF...etc) is the best to export to from core date?
2- I need to send file via mail from the App itself so keep this in mind
Appreciate if you could divert me to youtube tutorial or Stackoverflow question where I can find code for what I need. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Thanks Tom, appreciate it. Hope someone can answer me

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the exact same thing.  I am exporting my data to XML using this code:
https://github.com/skjolber/xswi/blob/wiki/SerializingObjectsToXML.md

If you export each of your entities in Xcode (Click your Data Model and then click Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass) you can add the code to each of the subclasses.

From there you should be able to create an XML file with all your data.